# React MomentJS get duration from start time and end time

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I've been trying to figure what's the best way to calculate duration of an event.

I have a Collection with the following fields:

```
type Event {
 ..
 startsAt: "HH:mm MM-DD-YYYY"
 endsAt: "HH:mm MM-DD-YYYY"
 ..
}
```

Ideally I would like to save

```
duration: String!
```

in my GraphQL mutation, when creating an Event.

Could someone advise me how could this be done?

**My stack:**

- React
- Apollo
- GraphQL

**I have the following installed:**
 ..

- MomentJS
- React Moment

..

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jordan Enev - thanks a lot for quick response! For some reason after trying this it threw an error ".diff" is not a function, I'm assuming I had to import something additionally. Also I ended up making a radical decision to switch to Unix timestamps.

With Unix Timestamp this is how I achieved my goal:

Add plugins `npm install moment-duration-format` and import it:

```
..
import momentDurationFormatSetup from "moment-duration-format";


..

momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);
  const durationSeconds = (endsAt - startsAt) / 1000;
  const duration = moment.duration(durationSeconds, "seconds").format("mm");

..
```

also above I wrapped moment in a HOC `momentDurationFormatString()`, provided by the newly imported plugin

-then with React Moment render it:

```
..
import Moment from "react-moment";

..

<Moment unix format="dddd, Mo MMM, H:mm">
          {startsAt / 1000}
</Moment>
..
```

Comment: The error is thrown because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093266/diff-is-not-a-function-in-moment-js). However, I'm happy that you resolve it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Having start(`startsAt`) and end(`endsAt`) dates you can easily calculate the duration on the Front-end side, somewhere in your React components.

Something like that:

```
// Convert `startsAt` and `endsAt` strings to moment date objects
const start = moment(state.Event.startsAt)
const end = moment(state.Event.endsAt)

// Calculate the duration
// Keep in mind you can get the duration in seconds, days, etc.
const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
const hours = duration.asHours()
```